# How to pass a variable value to vb variable obtained from input text field in JavaScript on aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an input text field, and I have applied autocomplete on it. When I select a value from autocomplete dropdown, I want to save it in Vb variable without any postback.
I obtained the value in JavaScript.
Like this.

Below is my HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="StringValue" id="StringValue" value="<%Response.Write(str)%>"/>
                <input type="text" id="param" name="param" style="height: 21px; width: 300px;" size="24"
                    class="inp-form" placeholder="Enter Account Name" onchange="myFunction()" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="AccountName"/>
```

And this is My JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = alert(document.getElementById('param').value);
        var y = alert(document.getElementById('AccountName').value);
        alert(y);
    }
</script>
```

Now I want the value of y in vb variable, which actually is the selected value from input field
Something like this:
    <% Dim accountNumber as String = y %>

How can I do that.
The problem is, that all this I have to do, on aspx page. I tried from VBScript too.

Comment: You cannot transfer data from client-side JavaScript to a server without actually sending it there. You will need a new HTTP request _after_ the selection was made, AJAX or not.

Comment: In your JavaScript function you would make an AJAX request to a server-side resource (page, handler, etc.) which would perform whatever server-side logic you want to perform.

Comment: Put the value in a HiddenField control

Comment: I made the request of AJAX, locally it was performing the very exact way, what was required but when I deployed it, AJAX went down. I still couldn't figure out the reason, but I too was able to make it without AJAX by sending data to server side.
Thanks a lot for your suggestions mates.
Bless you all.